# IP/UDP packet header details filtering

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, pcap

Hi i am trying to parse a Ip/Udp packet's header details actually to get the timestamp,port adresses etc. I know i can use  library to do this. So after googling a lot i found out a code to parse through a row packet in the following method

```
void dump_UDP_packet(const unsigned char *packet, struct timeval ts,
                     unsigned int capture_len)
{
    struct ip *ip;
    struct UDP_hdr *udp;
    unsigned int IP_header_length;

    /* For simplicity, we assume Ethernet encapsulation. */

    if (capture_len < sizeof(struct ether_header))
    {
        /* We didn't even capture a full Ethernet header, so we
         * can't analyze this any further.
         */
        too_short(ts, "Ethernet header");
        return;
    }

    /* Skip over the Ethernet header. */
    packet += sizeof(struct ether_header);
    capture_len -= sizeof(struct ether_header);

    if (capture_len < sizeof(struct ip))
    { /* Didn't capture a full IP header */
        too_short(ts, "IP header");
        return;
    }

    ip = (struct ip*) packet;
    IP_header_length = ip->ip_hl * 4;   /* ip_hl is in 4-byte words */

    if (capture_len < IP_header_length)
    { /* didn't capture the full IP header including options */
        too_short(ts, "IP header with options");
        return;
    }

    if (ip->ip_p != IPPROTO_UDP)
    {
        problem_pkt(ts, "non-UDP packet");
        return;
    }

    /* Skip over the IP header to get to the UDP header. */
    packet += IP_header_length;
    capture_len -= IP_header_length;

    if (capture_len < sizeof(struct UDP_hdr))
    {
        too_short(ts, "UDP header");
        return;
    }

    udp = (struct UDP_hdr*) packet;

    printf("%s UDP src_port=%d dst_port=%d length=%d\n",
           timestamp_string(ts),
           ntohs(udp->uh_sport),
           ntohs(udp->uh_dport),
           ntohs(udp->uh_ulen));
}
```

the thing is that i dont really know what are the parameters that i should use to invoke this function, ie, packet? timeval? etc am recieving my packets using socket api by listening to the port and using recv() function

```
for (;;)
    {
        len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        n = recvfrom(sockfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);
        //sendto(sockfd,mesg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
        printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");

        printf("%s\n from:%s port number:%d",mesg,inet_ntoa(cliaddr.sin_addr),cliaddr.sin_port);
        printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
```

Now here can i use the the mesg[] to pass to the above function to get the packet details or else is there any other way to receive the packet from a specific port. What value shall i use for the timeVal. Any help would be useful for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here the most relevant is how do you open your socket. Do you create the socket with `SOCK_RAW` flag? If yes, then `recvfrom` will receive RAW packets which you can directly send to your function. I am not sure about Windows, but on Linux the code creating a raw socket is like::

```
sockfd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));
```

The timeval argument is not directly relevant to the packet. It is supposed to be the time when you have got the packet. You will get it by calling `gettimeofday` after `recvfrom`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider using libpcap (Packet CAPture library), the guts of [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/).